# Very slow JOIN + ORDER BY query only in dev environment

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I have some production code and am setting up a new development environment. I found some pages were extremely slow to load. I profiled the code and found the slow query.

This query is taking **75 seconds** to run in the new dev environment:

```
SELECT `orders`.*, `users`.`user_flag`
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`
WHERE `cancelled` = '0' AND `is_estimate` = '0'
ORDER BY `orders`.`updated_date` DESC, `orders`.`order_date` DESC, `orders`.`creation_date` DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

- It is a new installation of MySQL via MAMP Pro on a Mac
- The version of MySQL is **5.7.25**

...

**Exactly the same query** on **exactly the same database schema** takes only **24 ms** on my old machine which has this version:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

So presumably something about the configuration of MySQL on the new machine is causing this slow query with a join and ORDER BY.

**What my.cnf settings should I be looking for?**

---

**Further tests**

(I cannot change the code as it is production code but did these tests to narrow down the problem)

Removing the `JOIN` brings the query time down to about **13ms**

```
SELECT `orders`.*
FROM `orders`
WHERE `cancelled` = '0' AND `is_estimate` = '0'
ORDER BY `orders`.`updated_date` DESC, `orders`.`order_date` DESC, `orders`.`creation_date` DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Removing the `ORDER BY` statement brings the time down to about **200ms** (still too slow)

```
SELECT `orders`.*, `users`.`user_flag`
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`
WHERE `cancelled` = '0' AND `is_estimate` = '0'
LIMIT 30;
```

(No `JOIN` or `ORDER BY` and it runs in 1.5ms)

---

The old MySQL config contains:

```
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

The new MySQL config has lots in it:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
password    = MAMP_root_password_MAMP
#port       = 9999
socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
#port       = 9999
socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 64M

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

table_open_cache = 64

MAMP_bind-address_MAMP

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
MAMP_skip-networking_MAMP

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

secure_file_priv=""


server-id   = 1

innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
sync_binlog = 0

[mysqldump]
password = MAMP_root_password_MAMP
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: To make it super clear - This query is very fast in production (<20ms). I am trying to resolve a development *environment* problem that is specific to this query.

Comment: Do you have access to the old config?  My first impulse is to compare the old and new config files.

Comment: @WillG Yes - adding the old config to the question

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in **mysql_error.log** hundreds of entries like this:

```
[Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name 
table_name. Please run mysql_upgrade
```

I ran this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade --host=localhost -uroot -proot
```

The problem now seems to be resolved – the initial query above is now taking about 20ms.

Perhaps it was corrupted on installation?

Comment: The upgrade processing adjusted for the newer version of MySQL, resulting in similar performance, with NO error messages in the log when you run your query.